NetSuite text search using Decode on createdby field so that the search can use a full list of createdby ids
I have about 3000 sales orders that I need to limit my RMA results against.  I tried a case statement but with this text field it really didn't work so I changed to decode.  I am just trying to return from 1 salesorder to start so I can ensure the formula is working...so far it won't limit my RMA returned to ONLY the RMA that matches this 'createdfrom' sales order.  Here is my code
DECODE({createdfrom},'Sales Order #SO136619','created from is Sales Order #SO136619','Unknown'
formula text limiter is 'is not' 'unknown'.  Instead of just returning the 1 (or in this case 2) RMAs created from this sales order, the results are returning ALL RMAs within the 2023 year.  I do have type = RMA and I do have mainline is false, tax line is false, status is pending refund (as this is the issue I'm trying to solve).
Help please....
I was expecting to return 2 RMAs created from Sales Order #SO136619 in my results.
Instead I got ALL RMAs with a created from sales order in the created from field.  :-(
